# Отправка уведомления в PHP

Tags: javascript, php, сокет, websocket

Для отправки сокета в JavaScript необходимо написать:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8090");
...
socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
```

А как этот текст перевести на PHP, то есть чтобы отправка сообщения происходила не в результате каких-то действий клиента, а по некоторым событиям, происходящим на сервере, например истекание срока подписки, обработки результатов запроса и т.д.?

На сервере постоянно работает демон server.php. Его текст:

```
require_once("chat.php");

define("PORT", "8090");
$chat = new Chat();
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socket, 0, PORT);
socket_listen($socket);

$clentSocketarray = array($socket);

while(true) {
    $newSocketArray = $clentSocketarray;
    $nullA = array();
    socket_select($newSocketArray, $nullA, $nullA, 0, 10);

    if(in_array($socket, $newSocketArray)) {
        $newSocket = socket_accept($socket);
        $clentSocketarray[] = $newSocket;
        $header = socket_read($newSocket, 1024);
        $chat->sendHeaders($header, $newSocket, "localhost", PORT);
        socket_getpeername($newSocket, $client_ip_address);
        $connectionACK = $chat->newConnectionACK($client_ip_address);
        $chat->send($connectionACK, $clentSocketarray);

        $newSocketArrayIndex = array_search($socket, $newSocketArray);
        unset($newSocketArray[$newSocketArrayIndex]);

    }

    foreach($newSocketArray as $newSocketArrayResource) {

        //1
        while(socket_recv($newSocketArrayResource, $socketData, 1024, 0) >= 1) {
            $socketMessage = $chat->unseal($socketData);
            $messageObj = json_decode($socketMessage);
            if ($messageObj->sender != null) {
                //$chatMessage = $chat->createChatMessage($messageObj->sender, $messageObj->message);
                $chatMessage = $chat->createChatMessage($messageObj);
                $chat->send($chatMessage, $clentSocketarray);
            }
            break 2;
        }

        ///2
        $socketData = @socket_read($newSocketArrayResource, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($socketData === false) {
            socket_getpeername($newSocketArrayResource, $client_ip_address);
            $connectionACK = $chat->newDisconnectedACK($client_ip_address);
            $chat->send($connectionACK, $clentSocketarray);
            $newSocketArrayIndex = array_search($newSocketArrayResource, $clentSocketarray);
            unset($clentSocketarray[$newSocketArrayIndex]);
        }

    }

}

socket_close($socket);
```

Текст chat.php (инструмент чата):

```
class Chat
{
    public function sendHeaders($headersText, $newSocket, $host, $port) {
        $headers = array();
        $tmpLine = preg_split("/\r\n/", $headersText);

        foreach($tmpLine as $line) {
            $line = rtrim($line);
            if(preg_match("/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/", $line, $matches)) {
                $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
            }
        }

        $key = $headers["Sec-WebSocket-Key"];
        $sKey = base64_encode(pack("H*", sha1($key."258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11")));

        $strHeader = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols \r\n".
            "Upgrade: websocket\r\n".
            "Connection: Upgrade\r\n".
            "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n".
            "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/messages/server.php\r\n".
            "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $sKey\r\n\r\n";

        socket_write($newSocket, $strHeader, strlen($strHeader));
    }

    public function seal($socketData) {
        $b1 = 0x81;
        $length = strlen($socketData);
        $header = "";
        if ($length <= 125) {
            $header = pack("CC", $b1, $length);
        } elseif ($length > 125 && $length < 65536) {
            $header = pack("CCn", $b1, 126, $length);
        } elseif ($length > 65536) {
            $header = pack("CCNN", $b1, 127, $length);
        }
        return $header.$socketData;
    }

    public function unseal($socketData) {
        $length = ord($socketData[1]) & 127;
        if ($length == 126) {
            $mask = substr($socketData, 4, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 8);
        } elseif ($length == 127) {
            $mask = substr($socketData, 10, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 14);
        } else {
            $mask = substr($socketData, 2, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 6);
        }

        $socketStr = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
            $socketStr .= $data[$i] ^ $mask[$i%4];
        }

        return $socketStr;
    }

    public function send($message, $clentSocketArray) {
        $messageLength = strlen($message);
        foreach ($clentSocketArray as $clentSocket) {
            @socket_write($clentSocket, $message, $messageLength);
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Основные события чата

    public function createChatMessage($messageArray) {
        $messageArray->type = "chat-box";
        return $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
    }

    public function newConnectionACK($client_ip_address) {
        $messageArray = array("type" => "connected", "message" => $client_ip_address);
        return $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
    }

    public function newDisconnectedACK($client_ip_address) {
        $messageArray = array("type" => "disconnected", "message" => $client_ip_address);
        return $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
    }

}
```

Следующий код не дал результата, то есть клиент, наблюдающий в режиме отладки получения сообщений, так их и не получил:

```
$fields = [
    "sender" => 0,
    "recipient" => 1,
    "message" => "Рас-рас-pac",
    "date_time" => "2019/05/21 03.00.00",
    "file" => null,
    "opened" => 0
];
$fields_code = json_encode($fields);
$fields_len = strlen($fields_code);
define("PORT", "8090");
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socket, 0, PORT);
socket_send($socket, $fields_code, $fields_len, 0);
```

Comment: Cron может вам подойдет ?

Comment: @Pavel8289, дело в том, что у меня уже есть демон, который работает циклически, и отлавливает сообщения, посланные через сокеты. Но эти сообщения я могу отправлять только с JavaScript. А как их отправлять с сервера, то есть при помощи PHP?

Comment: Я не селен на сокетах. Кто является инициатором срабатывания кода вашего, время или пользователь ? Если время то можно положить файл к вам на сервер, с функционал php таким как вам надо. А на хостинге настроить Cron задачи, чтоб дергал код каждую минуту/час/день. Если пользователь и на опрд. странице то этот же код подключить к той странице какой надо. И любой юзер какой задет будет код дергать, но не советую большое обращение к серверу он не выдержит и вас попросят или больше деняг или забанят временно за привышение активности.

Comment: Мой демон запущен не через Cron, а коммандой nohup php /home/admin/.../server.php &. И выполняется постоянно, т.к. там есть цикл while (true) {...}. Если нужно, я Вам могу прислать этот файл. Поймите, то, про что Вы говорите, у меня уже сделано, там проблем нет. Проблема лишь в том, что до этого файла server.php я могу достучаться только через JavaScript командой, указанной в тексте вопроса. Мне нужно также с PHP отправлять сокеты.

Comment: Сокеты как на сервере так и на клиенте имеют схожие методы. Разница в том, что клиент отправляет данные в сокет-сервер, а сервер конкретному клиенту (`socket.send()`, `server.onconnect => ..... $client->send('bla bla bla')`). Опишите какой инструмент Вы использовали для создания сервера.

Comment: @Владислав, в тексте вопроса я предоставил полный текст демона на сервере, ответственного за организацию чата. При обращении к нему командой JavaScript (socket.send(...)) этот демон работает исправно. Но попытка послать сообщение с PHP результатов не дала, код этой попытки я также добавил к тексту вопроса

Comment: @PavelSumarokov Извиняюсь, было поздно - код не заметил) Я бы Вам рекомендовал этот инструмент  [Workerman](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman), если речь идёт о вебсокете php. Очень удобная библиотека)